# Difference between setting parindent and hangindent

Tags: tex-core, indentation, luatex, paragraphs

Is there a difference between setting

- `\parindent` to 1em

and to setting

- `\parindent` to 0em, `\hangindent` to 1em, and `\hangafter` to -1

that shows in practical use? The nodes created by TeX are different, but does that show in typesetting at one point? One difference that I see is that the hang* settings are paragraph-local, but I don't care about that because I create every paragraph using LuaTeX's `tex.linebreak()`

This question is specific about LuaTeX, but I guess the answer applies to all engines.

Sample code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\linewidth 300pt

\newcommand\text{A wonderful serenity has taken possession of my entire soul, like
these sweet mornings of spring which I enjoy with my whole heart. I am
alone, and feel the charm of existence in this spot, which was created
for the bliss of souls like mine. I am so happy, my dear friend, so
absorbed in the exquisite sense of mere tranquil existence, that I
neglect my talents.}

\text

\hangindent=\parindent
\parindent 0pt
\hangafter=-1
\text

\end{document}
```

Comment: +1 for not using @@@@ lipsum as your filler text.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

LaTeX list environments use `\parshape` (for which `\hangafter` is a shorthand essentially) so the behaviour there is likely to be different.

But perhaps the first difference to bite is that LaTeX's mechanism to suppress paragraph indentation after section headings (and after mid-paragraph display environments) removes the parindent node but won't see hangafter.

Compare:

```
\section{aaa}

\text
```

in the two cases.

Answer (score 14):

The most important difference is that TeX remembers `\parindent`, but it resets `\hangindent` and `\hangafter` at the end of the paragraph.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\linewidth 100pt

\newcommand\texta{A wonderful serenity has taken possession of my entire soul, like
these sweet mornings of spring which I enjoy with my whole heart. I am
alone, and feel the charm of existence in this spot, which was created
for the bliss of souls like mine.}

\newcommand\textb{I am so happy, my dear friend, so
absorbed in the exquisite sense of mere tranquil existence, that I
neglect my talents.}

\texta

\textb

\hangindent=\parindent
\parindent 0pt
\hangafter=-1
\texta

\textb

\end{document}
```

[image]

The second `\textb` has no indentation. If you also leave a blank line after `\hangafter=-1`, you'll see that the second `\texta` is not indented, because of the resetting. Indeed a `\par` in vertical mode does *almost* nothing: what it does is resetting the paragraph shape parameters (`\hangindent`, `\hangafter`, `\parshape`, `\looseness`).

The behavior is identical in TeX, pdfTeX, XeTeX and LuaTeX.